# Why async code only executes properly when debugging

Tags: c#, async-await

This problem had me scratching my head for a while until I realised the basic mistake I'd made.

I found that an async method was not executing properly, except when I stepped right into it with my debugger.

Comment: @Pavel Anikhouski @yaakov @Klaus Gütter, this question was not caused by a typo, and it was not caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced.  It was caused because I made a method which was called in two places `async`, and only made one of the callers `await` it.  I could easily reproduce the problem.  As such, I would say that the stated reason for closure is incorrect.  The value of this question, IMO, is that it relates an observed behaviour which others might experience and search for to a simple resolution.

Comment: Re the case for reopening this question: I meant to say "others might experience and search for a simple resolution".  It's a problem caused by human error, and so is useful.  Human error is at the heart of many questions on SO because even developers are only human.

Answer (score 2):

With some help from a cardboard cutout of one of my colleagues, I realised that I had forgotten to make the caller `async`, and to `await` the result.